# Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "done")

Tags: shell

Here is my problem statement.

> Write a shell script that takes a name of a folder as a command line argument, and produce a file that contains the names of all sub folders with size 0 (that is empty sub folders)

This is my shell script.

```
ls $1
while read folder
do
        files = 'ls $folder | wc -l'
        if[$files -eq 0];
        then
                echo "$folder">>output.txt
                echo "File deleted"
        else
                echo "File is not empty"
        fi
done
```

When I execute my command (using 'sh filename'), it shows syntax error!

```
 Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "done")
```

Is there any wrong with my script?

Comment: Try removing line 6, thats where the issue is.

Comment: @HenslerSoftware Still not working! But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Any time you have a shell problem, your first step should be to analyze your script in http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the problems it reports. If after doing that your script *still* doesn't work, it's time to post to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget, in shell `[` is a binary that take parameters and return true or false (0 or 1).
`if` is a keyword that verifies the return of next binary called is true (0).

So, when you do

```
if[$files -eq 0]
```

Your shell understand nothing because it try to launch the `if[2` programm, and he find a `then` after without detecting the `if`.
For fix your problem, you have to put a space after your `if` and after the `[` because binary must have a space between between his name and their arguments.

```
ls $1
while read folder
do
        files = `ls $folder | wc -l`
        if [ $files -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "$folder">>output.txt
                echo "File deleted"
        else
                echo "File is not empty"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
ls $1
while read folder
do
        files=`ls $folder | wc -l`
        if [ $files -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$folder">>output.txt
                echo "File deleted"
        else
                echo "File is not empty"
        fi
done
```

Notice no space files=.., and there is `(back tick) not '(single quote)

Notice space between 'if' and '[' ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was facing the issue due to missing space after if. Added space between if and opening square brace, and script executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There may be spacing error:

Just do 2 steps:

1. run `hexdump -C yourscript.sh`
2. run `cat yourscript.sh | tr -d '\r' >> yournewscript.sh`

it will create new correct file then run new file.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got answers describing how your existing script needs to be fixed:

- no spaces around the `=` when you set the `$files` variable,
- backquotes instead of single ticks for your command substitution,
- a space after `if`, and spaces around the parts of the conditional expression.

Your script suffers from the [Parsing LS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) issue, in that filenames may be treated badly if they contain special characters like newlines. While you may think this isn't a big issue when all you want to do is check for the existence or nonexistence of files (i.e. count == 0), but the way you're doing it is still cumbersome, and encourages bad habits.

How about, instead consider:

```
while read folder; do
    files=0
    for files in $folder/*; do
        files=1
        break
    done
    if [ $files -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$folder" >> output.txt
    else
        echo "not empty: $folder" >&2
    fi
done
```

Instead of counting files in a command substitution and pipe, this uses a `for` loop to set a semaphore if any files exist. This will always be faster.

Note that this is POSIX-compliant. If your shell is a more advanced one, like bash or zsh, you have more elegant/efficient options available.